# How can I move icon from taskbar to system tray in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I want to move icons from taskbar to system tray in windows 7.

How can I do this?

Comment: I've edited your question to remove the software shopping aspect (which is off-topic).

Comment: @DavidPostill I understand your action, but given that Windows natively does not support this and it can only be done with software, this question still becomes too broad for that very reason.

Comment: @LPChip Feel free to VTC. Without my change it would be closed as software shopping anyway. At least the OP has an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I want to move icons from taskbar to system tray in Windows 7

**Option 1: [Tray Everything](https://github.com/maxgalbu/TrayEverything) (free):**

> TrayEverything is a lightweight portable application that minimizes
>   windows to the system tray even when the program lacks native support
>   for being parked in the tray.
>
> In addition to simply minimizing windows to the tray, TrayEverything
>   also has options to add a button to the title bar of windows for
>   minimizing to the tray, hot keys to minimize, and even using
>   inactivity as a trigger to send a window to the tray.
>
> If you'd like to keep a program running but don't need to tend to it
>   or would like to make sure nobody messes with it, TrayEverything can
>   minimize it without a visible icon in the tray and even
>   password-protect it.
>
> For more system tray goodness, check out [Trayconizer](http://lifehacker.com/396105/trayconizer-makes-any-program-a-permanent-system-tray-app) a program
>   that starts your program in the system tray from the moment it's run.
>
> TrayEverything is a free download for Windows only.

Source [TrayEverything Stashes Programs in the System Tray](http://lifehacker.com/5061417/trayeverything-stashes-programs-in-the-system-tray)

---

**Option 2: [Trayconizer](http://www.whitsoftdev.com/trayconizer/) (free):**

> Freeware application Trayconizer turns any application into a system
>   tray application in just a few steps.
>
> Unlike other previously mentioned minimize-to-system-tray apps like
>   TrayIt or 4t Tray Minimizer, Trayconizer starts applications in the
>   system tray from the moment you run them.
>
> To use it, you need to tweak the shortcut you're using to launch the
>   application (right-click shortcut and select Properties) by adding the
>   path to Trayconizer in front of the app like so:
>   C:\Path\To\Trayconizer.exe C:\Windows\Notepad.exe.
>
> Trayconizer is freeware, Windows only, requires no install, and
>   consumes a paltry 2MB of RAM.

Source [Trayconizer Makes Any Program a Permanent System Tray App](http://lifehacker.com/396105/trayconizer-makes-any-program-a-permanent-system-tray-app)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Tray Everything](https://github.com/maxgalbu/TrayEverything) or [Trayconizer](http://www.whitsoftdev.com/trayconizer/) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Comment: Tray Everything has been discontinued. You might want to update your answer.

Comment: @YSC What makes you say that? It is still available on the links I provided.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, but it's a very important if not essential factor for the decision which program to use when it comes to security, compatibility, bugfixing etc. That should be visible right away not just in the comments.