# How can I run a powershell script such that it does not create a tab on the toolbar?

Tags: powershell, toolbar

Most of the time I have a powershell script running while I work (its basically a local server). I never interact with it directly, its always a background task. Despite this, it still hogs space on my toolbar, which is kinda of annoying.

Is there an easy way to run my powershell script without it using a tab on my toolbar?

Additional notes:

- This is on my work computer, so third party tools probably wont be usable
- Other powershell scripts should still behave as normal with their own toolbar tab
- Ideally this will still be available on the hidden icon panel or something in case I need to kill/restart it mid-week

Comment: Have you tried to have windows scheduler start it?

Comment: This is not ideal because its a pain to manually kill, start or restart.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802127/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-without-displaying-a-window - will this help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move icon from taskbar to system tray in windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/1060870/how-can-i-move-icon-from-taskbar-to-system-tray-in-windows-7)